# When div is clicked clear the closest input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the input field that is closest to the div with class "removeDiv" to clear with that div is clicked.

I am also having an issue where after hiding the div by selecting Remove there isn't a way for the user to add it back in. But I may need to break that off into a second question.

Here is a truncated version of the code:

```js
//Add another designation
var count = 0,
    $allDivs = $('#flexible_designated_donation_element2_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element3_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element4_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element5_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element6_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element7_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element8_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element9_row, #flexible_designated_donation_element10_row');

$('#addAnother').click( function() {
    if( count < $allDivs.length ) {
        $allDivs.eq( count ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
        count++;

    }
});

$('.removeDiv').click( function() {
 $(this).closest('div[id*="flexible_designated_donation_element"]').hide();
 
});
```

```css
 div[id*='flexible_designated_donation_element']{
  display: none;
}

#addAnother {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.removeDiv {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flexible_designated_donation_element1_row" class="designated-giving-input-row form-row form-input">


<div id="flexible_designated_donation_element1designee_container" class="designated-giving-selection-container">
<label class="designated-giving-amount-label">Area of Support:</label><select name="flexible_designated_donation_element1primary" id="flexible_designated_donation_element1primary" size="1">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<optgroup label="Laboratory Schools">
<option value="1001">Classroom Gift for Teachers</option>

</optgroup>

</select>

</div>
<div class="designated-giving-amount-container">
<label for="flexible_designated_donation_element1name" class="designated-giving-amount-label">Gift Amount:</label>
<input type="text" name="flexible_designated_donation_element1name" id="flexible_designated_donation_element1name" value="" maxlength="15" onchange="fire_obs_comp_event('flexible_designated_donation_element1', this);">

<input type="hidden" name="flexible_designated_donation_element1submit" id="flexible_designated_donation_element1submit" value="true">

<div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
</div>

<div id="flexible_designated_donation_element2_row" class="designated-giving-input-row form-row form-input">


<div id="flexible_designated_donation_element2designee_container" class="designated-giving-selection-container">
<label class="designated-giving-amount-label">Area of Support:</label><select  name="flexible_designated_donation_element2primary" id="flexible_designated_donation_element2primary" size="1">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<optgroup label="Laboratory Schools">
<option value="1001">Classroom Gift for Teachers</option>

</optgroup>

</select>

</div>
<div class="designated-giving-amount-container">
<label for="flexible_designated_donation_element2name" class="designated-giving-amount-label">Gift Amount:</label>
<input type="text" name="flexible_designated_donation_element2name" id="flexible_designated_donation_element2name" value="" maxlength="15" onchange="fire_obs_comp_event('flexible_designated_donation_element2', this);">

<input type="hidden" name="flexible_designated_donation_element2submit" id="flexible_designated_donation_element2submit" value="true">

<div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
</div>


<div id="flexible_designated_donation_element3_row" class="designated-giving-input-row form-row form-input">


<div id="flexible_designated_donation_element3designee_container" class="designated-giving-selection-container">
<label class="designated-giving-amount-label">Area of Support:</label><select  name="flexible_designated_donation_element3primary" id="flexible_designated_donation_element3primary" size="1">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<optgroup label="Laboratory Schools">
<option value="1001">Classroom Gift for Teachers</option>

</optgroup>

</select>

</div>
<div class="designated-giving-amount-container">
<label for="flexible_designated_donation_element3name" class="designated-giving-amount-label">Gift Amount:</label>
<input type="text" name="flexible_designated_donation_element3name" id="flexible_designated_donation_element3name" value="" maxlength="15" onchange="fire_obs_comp_event('flexible_designated_donation_element3', this);">

<input type="hidden" name="flexible_designated_donation_element3submit" id="flexible_designated_donation_element3submit" value="true">

<div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
</div>

<div id="addAnother">+ Add Another
</div>
```

I have tried setting updating the script to the below:

```
$('.removeDiv').click( function() {
 $(this).closest('div[id*="flexible_designated_donation_element"]').hide ();
 $(this).closest('input[id*="flexible_designated_donation_element"]').val('');

});
```

Comment: Clear you mean remove or hide? can you please explain more about your expected output.

Comment: is the input a sibling of clicked div? your using .closest which selects an ancestor

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here or what's wrong with your snippet.  When I click Add Another it adds another, and when I click Remove X, it removes the div.  Please include a question in your question and clarify the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the parent `div` and `input`element's `id` contains same `flexible_designated_donation_element`, when clicking, you are targeting the `div` element not the `input`.

To clear the input value, you have to `find()` the input first:

```
$(this).closest('div[id*="flexible_designated_donation_element"]').find('input').val('');
```